# Show an infinite sigma algebra contains an infinite sequence of disjoint sets proof clarification

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am new to real analysis and was looking at this problem. 
I have been looking at the numerous answers to this question and I feel like I am close to understanding; however, I am not quite understanding this last, bolded part of this [Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088172/prove-that-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-contains-an-infinite-sequence-of-disjoint-s) (The first answer at the link).

Let $X$ be the whole space. First we show that

> there is $E\in\mathcal{M}$ such that the restriction of $\mathcal{M}$ to $E^c$ is still infinite.

If no such $E$ existed, then pick any $\emptyset\neq E\in\mathcal{M}$. The restriction of $\mathcal{M}$ to $E^c$ is finite. But the restriction to $E$ must also be finite because otherwise we could take $E^c$ for the role of $E$. Notice that $\mathcal{M}$ would be generated by the two finite, and disjoint, restrictions and that would imply it is itself finite.

**Now apply induction to define the infinite sequence. Pick the first $E_0$ with that property, $E_1$ with the same property from the restriction of the $\sigma$-algebra to $E^c$, $E_2$ from the restriction of the $\sigma$-algebra to $E^c\setminus E_1$, and so on** ...

I think that it is saying let $E_0$ be the first element so that the restriction of $E_0^c$ and $\mathcal{M}$ is infinite. But then I don't understand what $E_1$ is.

Can I say that $\mathcal{M}_1=\{F \cap E_0^c : F\in \mathcal{M}\}$. Then we have $\mathcal{M}_1$ is still a sigma algebra since it is closed under intersections and compliments. Then Take $E_1$ so that the restriction of $E_1^c$ and $\mathcal{M}_1$ is infinite.

I feel like this maybe isn't the right way to do it. I am a bit concerned that I can’t say that the $\mathcal{M}_1$ is a sigma algebra.

If someone could explicitly write for me what the $E_i$ are I would really appreciate the clarification. Thank you.

Comment: I feel like it is the way to do it. You should check out the previous posts on the same question.

Comment: That'd be awesome if I am right :)  I was reading all of the ones I could find on MSE and also online. That was the easiest for me to understand that I posted, but I was having trouble with the last part :/

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixing it now

Comment: You can visualize this process by drawing circles (Venn diagram). Basically, you can keep drawing non-empty, disjoint circles indefinitely. And the result is infinitely many non-empty, disjoint circles. You can also get some inspiration by thinking about the following question: why an infinite binary tree must have an infinite branch? Finally, for your problem, can you define a $\mathcal{M}_2$ by restricting $\mathcal{M}_1$ to $E_1^c$? Then you can get $E_2$ from $\mathcal{M}_2$. In general, you can get $\mathcal{M}_{i_1}$ from $\mathcal{M}_i$ and $E_i^c$.

Comment: @Y.Ding I think I can do that yes. I also was able to get help showing that the restriction of an element and the sigma algebra generates another sigma algebra so I can repeat my argument I believe infinitely many times :) as for the venn diagram, that is a great visualization, I was wondering how I know that a circle that I draw is actually one of the sets in the sigma algebra? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the comments above.*

---

Yes, your understanding is correct! You choose $E_0$ to be a nonempty member of $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}_1 := \{ F \cap E_0^c : F \in \mathcal{M} \}$ is infinite. You can check that $\mathcal{M}_1$ is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra, and now you can choose $E_1$ to be a nonempty member of $\mathcal{M}_1$ such that $\mathcal{M}_2 := \{ F_1 \cap E_1^c : F_1 \in \mathcal{M}_1 \}$ is infinite. And you can proceed like this inductively to complete the proof.

Comment: So $E_{i}$ is the desired result? But why they are disjoint?... Thanks.

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui The desired result is a sequence $\{ E_0, E_1, E_2, \dotsc \}$ of pairwise disjoint sets in the sigma algebra $\mathcal{M}$, not just $E_i$. They are pairwise disjoint by the way they are chosen itself.

Comment: So you mean given $E_{0}$, choose $E_{1}$ as a element of $\{F\cap E_0^{c}: F\in \mathcal{M}\}$ and then choose $E_2$ from $\{F\cap (E_0^{c}- E_{1}): F\in \mathcal{M}\}$, $E_3$ from $\{F\cap (E_0^{c}-(E_{1}\cup E_2)): F\in \mathcal{M}\}$so on... ?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui That’s right, but do note that at each stage $E_i$ is chosen such that the collection from which you pick $E_{i+1}$ is infinite.

Comment: Why is taking the compliment necessary at the first stage?