# An infinite $\sigma$-algebra contains an infinite sequence of disjoint sets

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking at folland 1.2 #3 and I used this:[Prove that an infinite sigma algebra contains an infinite sequence of disjoint sets and is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088172/prove-that-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-contains-an-infinite-sequence-of-disjoint-s?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer to help come up with a proof:

Folland 1.2 #3 Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an infinite $\sigma$-algebra. Prove $\mathcal{M}$ contains an infinite sequence of disjoint sets.

Choose $A_1$ to be any set in $\mathcal{M}$ such that $|\{B \cap A_1^c \mid B \in \mathcal{M}\}|\geq\infty$. Such a set exists, otherwise for any $C \neq \varnothing \in \mathcal{M}$,$|\{B \cap C^c\ \mid B \in \mathcal{M}\}|<\infty$, and $|\{B \cap C \mid B \in \mathcal{M}\}|<\infty$. Then $\mathcal{M}$ would be generated by $\{B \cap C^c \mid B \in \mathcal{M}\}$ and $\{B \cap C \mid B \in \mathcal{M}\}$ and $|\mathcal{M}|<\infty$ contradicting our assumption. Having chosen $A_1,...,A_{n-1}$, choose $A_n \in \{B \cap (A_1^c \setminus A_{n-1}) \mid B \in \mathcal{M}\}$ such that $|\{B \cap A_n^c \mid B \in \mathcal{M}\}| \geq \infty$. Then $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an infinite sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{M}$.

Would this answer be correct? Did I define the inductive sequence properly, in align with the user's answer from above? If not, what did I do wrong? Also, is there any easier way to do this problem?

Finally, I will try part $b$ of this problem that $|\mathcal{M}|\geq \mathfrak{c}$. For any $x \in [0,1)$ fix a ternary representation $x=\sum\limits_{k=1}c_k3^{-k}$. Define a function $\phi:[0,1) \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ by $\phi(\sum\limits_{k=1}c_k3^{-k})=\bigcup\limits_{\substack{k \geq1\\c_k=1}}A_k$. Since $\phi$ is injective $|\mathcal{M}| \geq \mathfrak{c}$. Again, is this correct? If so, is there any more intuitive way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seem quite right. There is no way in your solution to guarantee that $A_{n}$ is disjoint from say $A_{n-2}\in \{B\cap(A_{1}^{c}\setminus A_{n-1}): B\in \mathcal{M}\}$.

---

The point of the solution in the link is that we choose $A_{n}$ from a set whose members are disjoint from all the previous $A_{j}$. To illustrate the idéa: choose $A_{1}$ as you have done. Choose $A_{2}$ from $\{B\cap A_{1}^{c}:B\in \mathcal{M}\}$ such that $\{B\cap A_{1}^{c}\cap A_{2}^{c}: B\in \mathcal{M}\}$ is infinite. We do this because:

1. We need $A_{1}\cap A_{2}=\emptyset.$
2. We need infinitely many sets to be able to choose from in order to fill the whole sequence.

Assuming we have chosen the sets $A_{1},\dots, A_{n-1}$ according to the process above we have that

1. $A_{1},\dots,A_{n-1}$ are pairwise disjoint ($A_{i}\cap A_{j}=\emptyset$ if $i\ne j$)
2. The set $\{B\cap(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_{j}^{c}):B\in \mathcal{M}\}$ is infinite.

From here we can choose $A_{n}\in \{B\cap(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_{j}^{c}):B\in \mathcal{M}\}$ such that $\{B\cap(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} A_{j}^{c}):B\in \mathcal{M}\}$ is infinite. Then, $A_{n}\cap A_{j}=\emptyset$ ($1\leq j <n$) is immediate from where $A_{n}$ was chosen.